# Pandas aggregation: How to generate multiple new columns from one column and vise versa

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, aggregate

I am preprocessing the following `Pandas` dataframe.

[image: a]

For the same `assetid`, I want to find the first and last `AccountingDate` and create another column `isSold` based on following logic of `AccountingDate`.

```
if AccountingDate of all deals for same assetid is Null:
    isSold = False
else:
    isSold = True
```

At the same time, I want to find out for each `assetid`, the `Amount` of first and last `AccountingDate`.

In general `groupby` aggregation in `Pandas` goes like this:

```
df.groupby('assetid').agg({'A', func})
```

However my aggregation functions is lot more complicated, from `AccountingDate` to generate 3 columns `FirstAccountingDate`, `LastAccountingDate`, `isSold`; from `AccountingDate` and `Amount` combined, to generate `FirstDealAmount` and `LastDealAmount`.

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Could you explain `if all deals for same assetid is Null:` more?

Comment: @Dawei I meant accountingdate for all deals with the same assetid are all null

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the `first date` and `last date`, and check if both of them is `null`. You can do it by the following code.

```
print(df)

  assetId       date
0      1,        NaT
1      1, 2018-10-01
2      1, 2018-10-02
3      1, 2018-10-03
4      4,        NaT
5      4,        NaT
```

```
def isSold(date_array):
    last = date_array.max()
    first = date_array.min()
    return pd.isnull(last) & pd.isnull(last)

result = df.groupby("assetId").date.apply(isSold).reset_index()
print(result)
```

It gives:

```
  assetId   date
0      1,  False
1      4,   True
```